# SmartDevice CAB project CAB file could not be created

Tags: windows-mobile, compact-framework, cab

I am creating CAB file for SmartDevice Project(built for Windows Mobile 6)
I am getting following error

```
Error: CAB file "C:\SmartDevice2\Debug\SmartDeviceCab2.CAB" could not be created

ERROR: The Windows CE CAB Wizard encountered an error.  See the output window for more information.
```

I have checked [Windows Mobile Compact Framework Build Error: CAB file … could not be created](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21384107/windows-mobile-compact-framework-build-error-cab-file-could-not-be-created) and moved my solution to C Drive,
but still problem is not resolved.

Comment: Make sure the destination is writable and that there is no existing CAB that it's trying to overwrite.  In reality the CAB project sucks and you're probably going to have more luck going to a manual cabwiz call from a command line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Project in D Drive is not any issue for CAB Project building.
I have changed few things.

- Remove Spaces from Project Directory
- Any Dependency files(DLL) should be added manually. If any detected dll added in Setup project, then exclude those files.

I don't have any information why it is working in this scenario, but with these changes, I am able to build project.

Answer (score 0):

**Ways to Resolve this issues**

**1.** Make sure that dependencies are detected from your actual project to deployment project.

**2.** Make sure, all dependencies are in the same Drive (e.g, D: or E: or C:) and check if any duplicated dependencies are there. if duplicated is there, remove it. Because, cabwiz.exe
will detect and raise error if any kinds of dependencies violation.

**3.All reference must be in the cabwiz.exe installed drive or your project drive not any other drives**

I faced  this problem. Finally, I fixed this problem by Excluding some dependencies from deployment not in the actual project. And, i changed the references into the same drive where my cabwiz.exe was installed.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you @Harsh!

After moving my old VS2008 installation to D: (still supporting old WinCE projects) I could no longer get the CAB project to compile. Previously my VS2008 was installed on C: and my projects were all on D: and everything worked fine (in-spite of project being on a different drive to CABWiz.exe). Once I re-installed VS on D: the CAB failed with no specific error in the output tab.

After renaming the project folder to remove spaces, everything started working again. Best of all, an unrelated issue that had appeared after upgrading to Win10 where VS2008 would crash whenever it lost focus, has miraculously disappeared.

I had no issue with the CAB wizard detecting and adding its own dependencies.