# Distributing windows ce application

Tags: c#, windows-ce

I'm currently developing an app for windows compact edition with Visual Studio.
Everytime i compile the app, vs2008 will only generates .exe file extension. I can execute it directly on windows ce device after copy-paste it to the device.

What i want to do is creating application installer wizard. I have tried following tutorial but it doesn't work for me

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa446504.aspx

This is what i've done:

1. Adding new project which the project type is "Smart Device CAB Project", i give it a name SmartDeviceCab1, and this is the project structure
   See image tag 1
2. I keep the other settings use the default value and build the SmartDeviceCab1 project, and this is the result: see image tag 2

Here is the screenshot
[Screenshot of what i've done](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R5qgU.jpg)

Can anyone here give me solution?

Comment: *"nothing works for me"* is not a terribly useful problem description. What exactly happens when you try to follow the steps in the first link you mentioned ([here's a VS2008 version, by the way](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zcebx8f8(v=vs.90).aspx))? Where exactly do you get stuck? Please update your question with the required information. Otherwise, I'm afraid that it will be closed as "off-topic", since it does not contain a precise problem description.

Comment: Thanks for your response @Heinzi, i've edited my question, please check it

Comment: Googling for the error message brings up http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21384107/windows-mobile-compact-framework-build-error-cab-file-could-not-be-created , which seems to be exactly your problem. Does that solution help?

Answer (score -1):

You can create ".exe" of your application using **Inno** tool.

Please follow this below link for more information :

http://www.jrsoftware.org/isinfo.php